# Вылетает python при импорте numpy

Tags: python, numpy

С выходом python 3.11 numpy перестал работать
При простейшем коде

```
import numpy
```

Вылетает сам python (Python не отвечает. Закрыть программу).
Система: windows 10 x32 bit.
Может поддержка 32 битной винды прекратилась?

Path:

environ({'PROMPT': '$P$G', 'PYTHONIOENCODING': 'utf-8', 'COMSPEC': 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe', 'HOMEDRIVE': 'C:', 'SYSTEMDRIVE': 'C:', 'CHOCOLATEYLASTPATHUPDATE': '133200531085596488', 'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C:\Users\miros\AppData\Local', 'PUBLIC': 'C:\Users\Public', 'APPDATA': 'C:\Users\miros\AppData\Roaming', 'SYSTEMROOT': 'C:\WINDOWS', 'COMPUTERNAME': 'DESKTOP-12U81AG', 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6', 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '2', 'FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING': 'Internet Explorer', 'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\ProgramData', 'PROGRAMFILES': 'C:\Program Files', 'PROCESSOR_REVISION': '2505', 'USERPROFILE': 'C:\Users\miros', 'DRIVERDATA': 'C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData', 'USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE': 'DESKTOP-12U81AG', 'LOGONSERVER': '\\DESKTOP-12U81AG', 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'x86', 'ONEDRIVE': 'C:\Users\miros\OneDrive', 'USERNAME': 'vvarnovo', 'VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH': 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\', 'USERDOMAIN': 'DESKTOP-12U81AG', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\Program Files\Common Files', 'PATH': 'c:\users\miros\gcc\bin;c:\users\miros\gcc\libexec\gcc\i686-pc-mingw32\12.2.0;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\miros\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\miros\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\;C:\Users\miros\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\miros\yandex-cloud\bin;C:\Users\miros\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\miros\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Scripts\swig.exe;', 'WINDIR': 'C:\WINDOWS', 'TMP': 'C:\Users\miros\AppData\Local\Temp', 'FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING': 'Default', 'SESSIONNAME': 'Console', 'PATHEXT': '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC', 'PSMODULEPATH': 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules', 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER': 'x86 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel', 'OS': 'Windows_NT', 'PROGRAMDATA': 'C:\ProgramData', 'HOMEPATH': '\Users\miros', 'TEMP': 'C:\Users\miros\AppData\Local\Temp', 'CHOCOLATEYINSTALL': 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey'})

Питон запускаю и через Sublime Text 3 или через cmd (>>> py)

Comment: Поддержка не прекратилась. Как вы устанавливали Питон? Как вы его запускаете? Добавьте в вопрос значение переменной окружения `PATH`.

Comment: В вашем пути три раза упомянут каталог `...\Python310-32`. Это значит что когда вы запускаете Питон 3.11 он может обращаться к каталогам Питона 3.10 и загружать оттуда NumPy. Версии NumPy для разных питонов разные и несовместимые. Вычистите окружение так чтобы у Питона 3.11 не было шансов работать с библиотеками и пакетами от 3.10.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Я почищу и напишу Вам результаты.

Comment: Не помогло. Всё тоже самое(

Comment: На комментарий "не помогло" можно только ответить "это судьба". Если вы хотите помощи, нужно сообщать факты. Открывайте `cmd`, запускайте питон, выполняйте `import sys`, `sys.path`. Вставьте в вопрос полный лог из консоли начиная с момента запуска Питона.

Comment: sys.path
['', 'C:\\Users\\miros\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310-32\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Users\\miros\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310-32\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\miros\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310-32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\miros\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310-32', 'C:\\Users\\miros\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310-32\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: python -v прикреплю файлом

Comment: Видите `Python310-32` в выводе?

Comment: "Вставьте в вопрос полный лог из консоли начиная с момента запуска Питона."

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J9u9qV0cx58Y1qKfgmFljNvOLCbPBmtc/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 0):

Что-то у вас не так. Работает numpy

Только что проверил Python 3.11.1 на Windows 10: создал venv, в него установил numpy и запустил.

```
PS C:\Users\User\tmp\try-python> D:\Software\python3.11\python.exe -m venv venv
PS C:\Users\User\tmp\try-python> .\venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) PS C:\Users\User\tmp\try-python> pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.24.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (14.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14.8/14.8 MB 36.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.24.2

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
(venv) PS C:\Users\User\tmp\try-python> python
Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.24.2'
```

Удалите все следы Python 3.10, переустановите 3.11

Answer (score 0):

Для корректной установки необходимо скачать исходники с "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2c/d4/590ae7df5044465cc9fa2db152ae12468694d62d952b1528ecff328ef7fc/numpy-1.24.3.tar.gz". Распаковать архив и выполнить python setup.py build. (могут не установиться numpy.zeros)